# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'attempt to scroll to invalid index path

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, crash, uicollectionview

I've a crash in my app, I've 300 cells in my `UICollectionView` when I select cell NO. 300 show me this crash:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'attempt to scroll to invalid index path:  {length = 2, path = 0 - 300}'

**Code:**

```
var EnabledID = Int()
EnabledID = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "EnabledID")

if EnabledID == 0 {
    EnabledID = 1
    UserDefaults.standard.set(1, forKey: "EnabledID")

} else {
    let index = NSIndexPath(item: EnabledID, section: 0)
    self.myCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: index as IndexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
}
```

Please Help me to solve this problem :)

Comment: what is the value of `EnabledID` before the crash? If the value is negative you can fix in the first line to `EnabledID <= 0`

Comment: I edited my code @Matanya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check array count

```
if EnabledID < arr.count
{
    let index = NSIndexPath(item: EnabledID, section: 0)
    self.myCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: index as IndexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: You have 300 cells the final is 299